# Python: Why I can not convert map object to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble in converting map to list, when it can be converted to set

```
list_nums_2 = [2, 4, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 3, 1, 0]
evens = filter(lambda a: a % 2 == 0, list_nums_2)
print(set(evens))  # Out: {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}
print(list(evens)) # Out: []
```

I know it's not because it's converted to set already as from below it is clear that set can be converted to list

```
set_1 = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

print(list(set_1))  # Out: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: In Python 3.x `filter` returns an iterator. Passing it to `set`'s constructor consumes it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you ran `set(evens)` it consumed all of the items in the `filter` object. Therefore, there are no items available when you execute `list(evens)` and an empty list is returned.

The `filter` object is an iterator, which is iterable so you can call `next()` on it to get the next item:

```
>>> evens = filter(lambda a: a % 2 == 0, list_nums_2)
>>> evens
<filter object at 0x7f2f4c309710>
>>> next(evens)
2
>>> next(evens)
4
>>> next(evens)
8
>>> next(evens)
6
>>> next(evens)
0
>>> next(evens)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

The exception is because there are no more items in the `filter` object.